# php calculate price only for single row

Tags: php

I am trying to create cart which enable to calculate its profit based on the item price and the price that user wants to sell it. unfortunately, I cannot make it calculate just for certain row. it keep calculates for entire item. this is my code:

```
<?php
echo '<p><h3>Shopping Cart</h3></p>';

          if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {

            $total = 0;
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>Code</th>';
            echo '<th>Name</th>';
            echo '<th>Quantity</th>';
            echo '<th>Cost</th>';
            echo '<th>Sale</th>';
            echo '<th>Profit</th>';
            echo '</tr>';
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity) {

            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, qty, price FROM products WHERE id = ".$product_id);

            if($result){
              while($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
                $cost = $obj->price * $quantity; //work out the line cost
                $total = $total + $cost; //add to the total cost
                $sell = $_POST['sell'];
                $profit = $sell - $obj->price;
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$obj->product_code.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$obj->product_name.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$quantity.'&nbsp;<a class="button [secondary success alert]" style="padding:5px;" href="update-cart.php?action=add&id='.$product_id.'"> + </a>&nbsp;<a class="button alert" style="padding:5px;" href="update-cart.php?action=remove&id='.$product_id.'"> - </a></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$currency.$cost.'</td>';
                echo '<td><form action="" method="post"><input type="text" name="sell" />
       </form></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$currency.$profit.'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
              }
            }
          }
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$currency.$total.'</td>';
          echo '</tr>';
```

besides, I'm not sure how to define "sell" for the form / post function.
Thank you

Comment: Basically whats the question?

Comment: when i'm insert a price for an item, it will calculated for all items. but i want it calculate only for selected item.

Comment: Can you better explain your second question ? And how do you know an item is selected ?

Comment: Sounds like you need some JS support

Answer (score 0):

With your code you will have a `sell` variable for each item of your table :

```
Product1 sell
Product2 sell
Product3 sell
```

You should append the product's id in order to differentiate them

```
Product1 sell1
Product2 sell2
Product3 sell3
```

Example :

```
// assuming $_obj->product_code is a technical identifier (no spaces or special characters)
$sell = isset($_POST['sell'.$obj->product_code]) ? $_POST['sell'.$obj->product_code] : 0;
....
echo '<td><form action="" method="post"><input type="text" name="sell'.$obj->product_code.'" value="'.$sell.'" />
   </form></td>';
```

Comment: the sell still unidentified. the profit also still cannot be calculated just for single row

Comment: @Rahman changed the code to initiate the profit with 0 if it is unset. Better ?